# Flowering plant with star like leaf around bud

Tags: identification, houseplants, flowering

I bought this plant from nursery and forgot the name. It is a flowering plant, but the buds haven't bloomed yet.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Location is north India. Specifically Delhi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a cape jasmine (*Gardenia jasminoides*). It will produce white flowers that are extremely fragrant. It likes full sun, but tolerates light shade as well. For soil, it like consistently moist well-drained soil.

Comment: Will it attract pests?

Comment: I don't know, what did you have in mind?

Comment: because of the scent, I don't want rats or squirrels coming and eating the flowers or the buds of the plant.

Comment: Oh okay, no I don't think the scent will attract rodents. Some insect will be attracted though.